# Multiple file upload (client side)

Tags: javascript, flash, html, extjs, upload

I'm looking for multiple file upload component with alternative ways.
I need HTML5, Flash and normal upload support, depended by device.
I don't like FancyUpload, because it uses mootools and mootools is very big library.
Also I can't use jQuery, because I'm writing on Ext js and it's not good idea to use two big library like jQuery and Ext js.
I can write it myself but I don't have a time.

If everyone knows any library like this, please post link here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a big fan of [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)

Here is an example of all run times supported (Flash, HTML4, HTML5, etc...): http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php

You can also include only the run times you want.

Comment: Interesting link, combines all upload methods currently available

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ExtJS 4 wrapper I wrote for SWFUpload: https://github.com/JarvusInnovations/Ext.ux.SWFUpload

I'm interested in having a more robust ExtJS4 upload widget though that supports HTML5 and normal form upload too. Maybe we can build one if nothing else turns up.