# Multiple HTTP File Uploads

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash, upload

I'm looking for a tool to facilitate mulitple webpage file uploads from a single file browse dialogue.  I know this has been asked previously, but I can't find anything current.

I'd like to check file size prior to upload, and I gather Flash is still the only way to do that cross-browser?

Ideally, I'd like an upload progress metre.  I'll be using Linux and Apache servers, but don't have access to install add-ons such as PHP APC.  Again, I assume something flash-based is the only option there?

I've looked at SWFUpload, but that appears to be another of these projects where the developers have become quite zealous and turned a simple concept into a full suite of tools for the masses.  It seems quite cumbersome and I don't think I want to use it for my purpose.

I'd prefer not to have to write something from scratch for this.  Could someone recommend me something or perhaps suggest a non-Flash alternative if there is one?  I do need full cross-browser compatibility without too many layers of degradation, so anything HTML 5 probably isn't what I want.

Thanks

Comment: The question doesn't suggest that I'd like or require that, or anything close.

Comment: swfupload is pretty easy to integrate...only alternative is an ajax kinda thing and even that you still have to select files individually

Comment: OK, thanks.  I think people should be required to comment with an explanation if they choose to downvote a question!  The first comment was deleted. Perhaps I should remove the commentry on 'zealous development'. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned earlier today ( [Multiple file upload (client side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740246/multiple-file-upload-client-side/8762905#8762905) )
I am a big fan of Plupload which can check file size, show progress bar, single dialog for multiple files, and supports things other than Flash if needed.

Comment: ah I stand corrected..looks like that plupload has a html5 multi upload thing..neat!

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I'd not come across that.  I didn't know if the name hinted at perl, which is one option I was pondering for progress metres.  I see it doesn't.